# MacBook Pro 13, 2011 - can't upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: osx-lion

I need to upgrade to something greater than Lion 10.7.5 to install ibooks.  I tried downloading El Capitan, but when I click the download button, it won't download.  I have 256G of space. Any suggestions?

Comment: How much of that 256 GB is *free* space? How are you trying to download El Capitan? From the Mac App Store? What error message or other visual feedback do you get when it doesn't download? What does the "All Messages" log in the Console utility say when this happens?

Comment: It is all free space, I get no message. I am trying to download from the Apple website, and when I click the download button it looks like it is going to download but then immediately stops. No explanation, no message. According to the website requirements, I do have the right resources.

Comment: Did you look at the logs? Anything in the logs?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to look up the logs.

Comment: Find your Applications folder. In it, find your Utilities folder. In it, find the "Console" Utility. In it, find the "All Messages" log. With this open, try to download El Capitan from the Mac App Store again. See if any new messages appear in the log when you do that. Copy and paste those log messages into your Question. Also use the sidebar of the Console utility to find the "Installer.log" and see what it says. Also consider rebooting, and running Disk Utility's "Repair Disk" and "Repair Permissions" fixes on your boot volume (main hard drive).

Comment: Here is the log info when trying to download El Capitan

Comment: Here is intall.log: Apr 23 08:43:26 localhost crsud[48]: crsud: Starting
Apr 23 08:43:36 Sandras-MacBook-Pro crsud[48]: Error encountered - scheduling retry: Error Domain=CUErrorDomain Code=-1199 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x102012550 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}
Apr 23 08:44:02 Sandras-MacBook-Pro crsud[48]: crsud: Exiting.

Comment: Here is all I got after hitting download: 4/23/16 9:05:36.112 AM [0x0-0x12012].com.apple.Safari: Vector smash protection is enabled.